# beginner c++ draw house program

Tags: c++, function, void

New at c++ so if I get any terms wrong please don't ridicule me. I am trying to write a program that will draw ask the user for units and then draw house using functions. The problem that I am having is in my `drawcone` function Here is my progress so far.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void drawcone(int height);
void drawHorizontalLine(int numXs);
void draw2VerticalLines(int numSpaces, int numRows);
void drawOneRow(int numSpaces);
void getDimensions(int& width, int& height);
void drawbox(int width, int height);

int main(){

int width;
int height;

    getDimensions(height, width);
    drawcone(height);
    drawHorizontalLine(width);    
    draw2VerticalLines(width - 2, height - 2);   
    drawHorizontalLine(width);



return 0;
}

void drawbox(int width, int height){

    drawHorizontalLine(width);    
    draw2VerticalLines(width - 2, height - 2);   
    drawHorizontalLine(width);

}

void drawcone(int height){

    int base = height * 2;

    int r = 0;

    while ( r != height){

        int c = 0;
        while (c != base){

            if(c==height-r || c==height+r)
                cout << "X";
            else
            cout << " ";
            c++;

}
    cout << endl;
    r++;
}
}

void drawHorizontalLine(int numXs)
    {               
        int count;

        for (count = 0; count < numXs; count++){
            cout << "X";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


void draw2VerticalLines(int numSpaces, int numRows)
    {                          
        int rowCount;

        for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < numRows; rowCount++){
            drawOneRow(numSpaces);
        }
    }

void drawOneRow(int numSpaces)
    {
        int spaceCount;

        cout << "X";
        for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < numSpaces; spaceCount++){    
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "X" << endl;
    }

void getDimensions(int& width, int& height){

cout << "Enter the width of the house" << endl;
cin >> width;

cout << "Enter the height of the house" << endl;
cin >> height;

}
```

The correct sample output would look like this

```
   X
  X X
 X   X
 XXXXX
 X   X
 X   X
 XXXXX
```

My current output looks like this

```
    X
   X X
  X   X
 X     X
XXXX
X  X
X  X
XXXX
```

I would like the cone to be slightly smaller so it will be proportionate to the box. I would also prefer an answer that does not involve modifying the `drawbox` function. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What does stepping through the code with the debugger tell you is causing the problem?

Comment: you have width and height in the wrong order when you call getDimensions, so the values will be flip flopped.

Comment: Another problem is that you assumed that the base of the roof is twice the height, while just a small peek at the correct output would show that it isn't. You already know how wide the roof should be – the height is unknown. (But you don't need to compute height of it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution. However, the cone will be symmetrical only if the width is odd.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void drawcone(int height);
void drawHorizontalLine(int numXs);
void draw2VerticalLines(int numSpaces, int numRows);
void drawOneRow(int numSpaces);
void getDimensions(int& width, int& height);
void drawbox(int width, int height);

int main() {

    int width;
    int height;

    getDimensions(width, height);
    drawcone(width);
    drawHorizontalLine(width);
    draw2VerticalLines(width - 2, height - 2);
    drawHorizontalLine(width);

    return 0;
}

void drawbox(int width, int height) {

    drawHorizontalLine(width);
    draw2VerticalLines(width - 2, height - 2);
    drawHorizontalLine(width);
}

void drawcone(int width) {

    for (int i=0; i<(width/2 + width%2); i++) {

        for (int j=width/2-i; j>0; j--) {
            cout << " ";
        }

        drawOneRow(i*2-1);
    }
}

void drawHorizontalLine(int numXs)
{
    int count;

    for (count = 0; count < numXs; count++) {
        cout << "X";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void draw2VerticalLines(int numSpaces, int numRows)
{
    int rowCount;

    for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < numRows; rowCount++) {
        drawOneRow(numSpaces);
    }
}

void drawOneRow(int numSpaces)
{
    int spaceCount;

    cout << "X";
    if (numSpaces > 0) {
        for (spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < numSpaces; spaceCount++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "X";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void getDimensions(int& width, int& height) {

    cout << "Enter the width of the house" << endl;
    cin >> width;

    cout << "Enter the height of the house" << endl;
    cin >> height;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly easy to debug, it's printing out the wrong number of spaces for the 'roof' of the house.
The problem should be contained in the `while ( r != height)` block
try messing with the `else {cout << " ";}` with `else if(c%2==1){cout << " ";}`

Comment: Im not sure what you meant about that. I'm still new could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void roof(int height);
void hLine(int num);
void vLine(int spaces, int rows);
void row(int spaces);
void dimensions(int& width, int& height);
void box(int width, int height);

int main()
{
    int width;
    int height;
    dimensions(height, width);
    roof(height);
    hLine(width);    
    vLine(width - 2, height - 2);   
    hLine(width);

    return 0;
}
void box(int width, int height)
{
    hLine(width);    
    vLine(width - 2, height - 2);   
    hLine(width);
}
void roof(int height)
{
    int base = height * 2;
    int r = 0;
    while ( r != height)
{
    int c = 0;
    while (c != base)
    {
        if(c==height-r || c==height+r)
            cout << "*";
        else
        cout << " ";
        c++;
    }       
    cout << endl;
    r++;
}
}
void hLine(int num)
{               
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < num*2+1; count++)
    {
        cout << "-";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void vLine(int spaces, int rows)
{                          
    int numrows;
    for (numrows = 0; numrows < rows; numrows++)
    {
        row(spaces);
    }
}
void row(int spaces)
{
    int numspaces;
    cout << "{";

    for (numspaces = 0; numspaces < spaces*2+3; numspaces++)
    {    
        cout << "$";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}

void dimensions(int& width, int& height)
{
    cout<<"Enter the width of the house"<<endl;
    cin>>width;
    cout<<"Enter the height of the house"<<endl;
    cin>>height;
}
```